# Formating a ultimatelistctrl in wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

i would like have some small layout changes and dont know if they are possible.

Here is my ultimatelistctrl with a header

[image: Ultimatelistctrl]

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Apr 20 13:00:09 2020

@author: Odatas
"""


import wx
from threading import Thread
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class Uploader(wx.App):


def __init__(self,redirect=False,filename=None):
    wx.App.__init__(self,redirect,filename)        
    self.frame=wx.Frame(None)

    self.width=905
    self.header=wx.Font(16, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, "Arial")
    self.ListText=wx.Font(12, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, "Arial")

    #panel
    self.panel=wx.Panel(self.frame)

    self.panelForHeading=wx.Panel(self.panel,-1,size=(self.width,50))
    self.panelForHeading.SetBackgroundColour((91,155,213))


    #widgets
    self.NameOfDatabase=wx.StaticText(self.panelForHeading,-1)
    self.NameOfDatabase.SetLabel(' Some Header')
    self.NameOfDatabase.SetFont(self.header)

    #ultimatelist
    self.FileList=ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self.panel,size=(self.width,600),agwStyle=wx.LC_REPORT|ULC.ULC_USER_ROW_HEIGHT|ULC.ULC_SINGLE_SEL|ULC.ULC_BORDER_SELECT|ULC.ULC_AUTO_TOGGLE_CHILD)
    self.FileList.SetUserLineHeight(30)
    self.FileList.SetHeaderHeight(40)

    #First Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Select"
    info._kind=1
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(0,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(0,100)

    #Second Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Name"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(1,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(1,300)

    #Third Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Type"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(2,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(2,150)

    #fourth Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Date modified"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(3,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(3,150)

    #Fifth Column
    info=ULC.UltimateListItem()
    info._mask=wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT|wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE|wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT|ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
    info._image=[]
    info._format=0
    info._text="Status"
    self.FileList.InsertColumnInfo(4,info)
    self.FileList.SetColumnWidth(4,200)



    #sizer
    self.TopLevelSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.HeaderSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    #add widget to sizer
    self.HeaderSizer.AddStretchSpacer()
    self.HeaderSizer.Add(self.NameOfDatabase,0, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL)
    self.HeaderSizer.AddSpacer(5)

    self.TopLevelSizer.Add(self.panelForHeading,0,wx.ALL)
    self.TopLevelSizer.Add(self.FileList,1,wx.ALL)

    self.panelForHeading.SetSizer(self.HeaderSizer)
    self.panel.SetSizer(self.TopLevelSizer)

    #layout
    self.TopLevelSizer.Fit(self.frame)
    self.panel.Layout()
    self.frame.Show()

    self.TestInsertList()


def TestInsertList(self):

    for i in range(5):
        self.FileList.InsertStringItem(i,"",it_kind=1)
        self.FileList.SetItemFont(i,self.ListText)
        self.FileList.SetStringItem(i,1,'File '+str(i))







if __name__=='__main__':
    app=Uploader()
    app.MainLoop()
```

1. I would like the selection board to be black
2. I would like the selection boarder without the round edges. It should just go straight to the end of the window and no horizontal line at all should be visible. Alternativ no round edges bud maximal edgy edges.
3. The seperators between columsn in the header should also be blue.
4. A line under the header. But nowhere else.

I didnt finde particular options about this. Is there anything i can do to archive it in reasonable times? As you can see its only details so i dont want to spend hours on it. Maybe is just dont know a set or flag that would archive that.

Thanks for your help.